# Animation reset

Tags: jquery, css, animation, click, fade

I have the following code that, when the blue block is clicked, animates an overlay in (with a second block) which then animates back out when it is clicked a second time. Click the blue block a second time and it doesn't work because the overlay is not hidden. I tried throwing another `.hide()` in there but it broke the animation. Any help would be appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/sC3cH/6/)

```
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="fullscreen">
    <div class="content_box">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
.fullscreen {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: orange;
}
.content_box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3000;
    top: 150px;
    left: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.fullscreen').hide();
});
$(function(){
    $(".box").click(function(){
        /* Fades in overlay */
        $(".fullscreen").fadeTo(500,.5);
        $(".content_box").show().animate({left: 200, opacity: 1},400);
});
});
$(function(){
    $(".fullscreen").click(function(){
        /* Fades in overlay */
        $(".content_box").show().animate({left: 400, opacity: 1},400);
        $(".fullscreen").fadeTo(500,0);
});
});
```

Comment: When is it supposed to fade out ?

Comment: The background/yellow box should animate back out when any part of the page is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The `.fullscreen` element is still overlaying, obsucring the next clicks.

In the last function, change the last line to

```
$(".fullscreen").fadeTo(500,0,function(){$(this).hide();});
```

So it really disappears. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sC3cH/8/).

Comment: Thanks. Should I use display: none at the beginning instead of hide() in that case? Just to keep things consistent?

Comment: No need, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: Moreover, instead of using `.css` you can use .`hide` in the function there. I'll actually update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sC3cH/9/)

As you can see, I replaced the fadeTo by fadeOut, which does hide the block after the fading out.

```
$(".fullscreen").fadeOut(500);
```

Hoping that it is what you asked for.

Comment: @Andy It is now fixed, it was a failed copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

When you're changing the opacity to 0, the `.fullscreen` is still actually above the blue box, so when you click the next time, you're actually clicking the `.fullscreen` and not the blue box, so you can do the following:

Initially, make it always `opacity: 0.5;` and hide it `display:none;`.

And in JQUERY, use `.fadeIn(500)` and `.fadeOut(500)` to show and hide the `.fullscreen` but with a smooth effect.

```
$(".box").click(function(){
        /* Fades in overlay */
    $(".fullscreen").fadeIn(500);
    $(".content_box").show().animate({left: 200, opacity: 1},400);
});
$(".fullscreen").click(function(){
        /* Fades in overlay */
        $(".content_box").show().animate({left: 400, opacity: 1},400);
    $(".fullscreen").fadeOut(500);
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKagT/)